# The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

What I have "Tried"
1. Adding reference to , System.Core, System.Xml.Linq, System.Data.Linq by right clicking on my website root as well as in individual pages.

1. By adding assembly in web.config as shown below,

   ```
   <configuration>
     <connectionStrings>
      <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data       Source=|DataDirectory|\PayrollSystem_DB.mdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
   </connectionStrings>
   <location path="~/Styles/StyleSheet.css">
   <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true">
           <assemblies>
               <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
               <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
               <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
           </assemblies>
       </compilation>
       <authentication mode="Forms">
           <forms loginUrl="~/Login/frmLogin.aspx"/>
       </authentication>
       <authorization>
           <deny users="?"/>
       </authorization>
   </system.web>
   </location>
   </configuration>
   ```

It was working fine in the project earlier today. I ran into first web.config issue when I added

```
  <authentication> and <authorization>
```

tags my CSS stop working on the login page. Then I added Location tag as shown above and it fixed my css for login page but then I started getting this Linq error on every page.

I searched online it was advised it is web.config issue so I should add the reference for System.core assembly in the web.config file which I did but still same issue.

Comment: Devs, or just you? You're certain you're not just making a mistake?

Comment: You have embedded your entire `system.web` tag inside of a `location` referring to `css`.  In other words none of that is applying to anything except the stylesheet page...

Comment: Point is not if I am making mistake point is why would I have to go through these kind of hacks?

Comment: Why is `<location>` wrapping `<System.Web>`? I don't think that is correct

Comment: At this point it doesn't matter <location> is there or not, even if I remove it still getting same error.

Comment: dont understand why so many downvotes...perhaps this will fetch me one :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## R00T CaUsE

1. Adding

   ```
   <authorization>
   ```

   tag with the code shown in above question would make any anonymous user from accessing any page other than Login, as each request will be redirected to LogIn Page with no other content allowed from server including basic **CSS**.
2. Suggested solution 1 on the web was to add

   ```
     <location>
   ```

   tag which works for css but causes issue with the System.Linq.

Here is the solution for the StUpIdItY. First of since nothing was working I saved web.config contents and deleted web.config and recreated from scratch as follows.

## Step1

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
<system.web >
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
        <forms  loginUrl="~/Login/frmLogin.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization >
        <deny  users="?"  />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

This first step took Linq errors away.

## Step 2

Problem with this approach is since I am using external CSS file it will not apply to LOGIN page as

```
      <authorization >
        <deny  users="?"  />
    </authorization>
```

will block any anon user. 
You can still use CSS by having css in separate folder and adding another web.config file under the folder where your external CSS is. In my case my css file was, StyleSheet.css under Styles folder. So I just added web.config there as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now my css is working fine, as well as I can use LogIn page and Linq.

Thanks to MICROSOFT for wasting my time on these issues but I hope I can save frustrations to many in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try clearing the WebsiteCache folder and see if that helps. (Back it up before you delete its contents)

https://superuser.com/questions/65615/visual-studio-2008-does-not-remember-my-default-page-for-web-sites/65678#65678

Comment: Tried this and cleared the cache but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you have your system.web inside location. And location path is CSS file. So, seems that your assemblies effectively missing from the project. Does it work without location element? Or without system.web embedded inside location?

Comment: I removed the location but it doesn't work still.